# COM Exception when using Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

Tags: c#, office-interop, interopservices

Hello Guys good afternoon (argentina time), i had recieved a project where the system formats a word document according to some requirements from the client. The word document that i recieve is on .doc and and the word document that i export or create under a different format or internal design is .docx. The core thing is that this same code used to work with Office12 assemblies, but when i added the new assemblies which are Office15, It crashed.

The sample code that i am using for the portion of the proyect where the flow crashes is the following:

```
public void Prueba()
        {
            // Open word and a docx file
            var wordApplication = new Application() { Visible = false };
            string strPath=@"<Path>" ;
            string strNombreArchivo = "<Name of the doc>.doc";
            string strddd = "Foo.docx";
            var docOriginal = wordApplication.Documents.Open(strPath+strNombreArchivo, ReadOnly: true);
            //var docddd = wordApplication.Documents.Open(strPath + strddd, ReadOnly: false);
            var docNuevo = wordApplication.Documents.Add(DocumentType: WdDocumentType.wdTypeDocument);



            docOriginal.Content.Copy();
            docNuevo.Content.Paste();
            var docAUsar = docNuevo;




            Range searchRange = docAUsar.Range();
            searchRange.Find.ClearFormatting();
            int nextSearchStart = searchRange.Start;
            searchRange.Start = nextSearchStart;
            Paragraph ParagraphParrafo = searchRange.Paragraphs.First;
            nextSearchStart = ParagraphParrafo.Range.End;
            String titleText = ParagraphParrafo.Range.Text;

            try
            {
                // This is the point where the code crashes.
                searchRange.InsertParagraphAfter(); 
                docAUsar.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            }

            // Close word
            wordApplication.Quit();  
            this.Close();
        }
```

The exception message is:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  HelpLink=wdmain11.chm#37373
  HResult=-2146823683
  Message=This method or property is not available because this command is not available for reading.
  Source=Microsoft Word
  ErrorCode=-2146823683
  StackTrace:
       en Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
       en WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1.Prueba() en C:\Users\Dleekam\Google Drive\Proyectos\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs:línea 58
       en WindowsFormsApplication3.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) en C:\Users\Dleekam\Google Drive\Proyectos\WindowsFormsApplication3\WindowsFormsApplication3\Form1.cs:línea 25
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       en System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
  InnerException:
```

Interesting things:

1. when i use a new file it doesnt crash.
2. when i write the content by hand it doesnt crash.
3. when i copy and paste the content or part of the content it crashes.
4. I delete the content in the new document  and try it again, crashes.

I believe it is something related with the formatting of the words or of the paragraphs in the document original document. Since it only happens when i use the content of the original document. But i am not sure yet what is going on, or how to handle this, or how to do a workaround of this. Since that the exception is not so descriptive (i know, i am not always going to recieve the specific information or error message that i need) but i already have search the web looking to see if someone have had the same, related or unrelated kind of error.

Any help or orientation will and is highly appreciated, thank you all for your time reading and understanding the code.

Kindest Regards
Douglas Leekam

Answer (score -1):

I was working on VS2010 but then i though on trying to open and run that section of the solution in VS2013 and i worked. So i must assume that VS2013 recognizes the elements in the 15 version of office and it doesnt raise an exception.

Thank you for reading.